# Pandas - apply multiplication after masking and df.where

Tags: python, pandas, masking

I can apply a mask to an entire dataframe and substitute True booleans with a given value, ex, 1.0, like so:

```
    0   1
 0  0.0 0.0 
 1  3.0 0.0
```

with:

```
mask = (df != 0.0)
df = df.where(mask, 1.0)
```

then:

```
    0   1
0   0.0 0.0 
1   1.0 0.0
```

But, instead of a constant `float` value, how can I substitute each True bool using a multiplication factor, such as, say, the cell value * 0.5, ending up with:

```
   0   1
0  0.0 0.0 
1  1.5 0.0
```

Comment: Neat. Make sure to also tag pandas questions [tag:python]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
df[mask] *= 0.5
```

Output:

```
     0    1
0  0.0  0.0
1  1.5  0.0
```

Comment: Perfect, cheers